# Finding and removing tuples with duplicated values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't mean situation like this:

```py
my_list = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d"), ("d", "f"), ("a", "b"), ("b", "c")]
```

and eliminating the second tuple `("a", "b")`, but rather something like:

```py
my_list = [("a", "b"), ("c", "c"), ("d", "f"), ("a", "b"), ("b", "b")]
```

and removing tuples `("c", "c")` and `("b", "b")`.

In the example above, the following one-liner does the job:

```py
my_list_cleared = [n for n in my_list if n[0] != n[1]]
```

But is there also a one-liner if there are three and more elements in tuples (like: `("a", "a", "b", "c")`)?

Comment: Check out [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: In the greater than 2 case, do you want to remove if all elements in the tuple are the same, or any 2 are repeating?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: all values should be unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if all elements in a list are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278122/checking-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-unique) where in your case the check is for each tuple and not the list as a whole

Comment: Yes, this too; it's a generic implementation of Cory Kramer's response. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: [testing whether a tuple has all distinct elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891726/testing-whether-a-tuple-has-all-distinct-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `set` of each tuple, which will remove duplicates. If that set is the same length as the original tuple, there were no duplicates, so keep that element. This can be done in a list comprehension and will work with tuples of arbitrary length.

```
>>> [i for i in my_list if len(set(i)) == len(i)]
[('a', 'b'), ('d', 'f'), ('a', 'b')]
```